# Remote desktop as different window/user?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, multiple-users, multiple-desktop

I've installed Windows 10 on my father's PC with 2 accounts: `User1` and `User2`. Is it possible for him to use `User1` and for me to use `User2` at the same time? I'll be connecting with some remote desktop software (preferably Microsoft Remote Desktop). Thanks!

---

EDIT: 1 account with multiple desktops would work for us, too, as soo as we don't see each other's work (I don't know if that's possible).

Comment: only 1 remote user at a time is allowed as far as know. But is a good question.

Comment: @Moab yeah, basically we want to use the same PC - he could be on the computer, I can login externally from my Mac. BTW, it's actually 1 remote user - the other one is local, right?

Answer (score 1):

1. Run -> gpedit.msc -> enter
2. Administrative Templates -> windows Component -> Remote Desktop Services -> remote desktop session host -> connections
3. Go to Restrict Remote Desktop Services users to a single Remote Desktop Services Session
4. Select Disabled. Click OK

following after this:

5. Go to Limit number of connections.
6. Select Enabled. Change ‘RD Maximum connections allowed’ to the desired connection allowed.
   (which will be 2)

Okay and then save these changes, this should allow mutiple connections to your computer.

Make sure to only do these changes to the computer that you are both connecting to!

Comment: Actually my question was - can he stays physically on the PC, I login remotely, and we both use the same PC as separate users? Basically use the same PC for the two of us separately?

Comment: @HristoTorbov this will allow this to happen

Comment: Are you sure this will work? To my knowledge it will throw the current user to the login screen as soon as a connection through RDP is made, and disconnects them when the local user logs in again.

Comment: An RDP session counts as a user and only on user at one time is allowed.

Comment: I'll try it tonight. I just saw that Windows Server 2019 can do this, I can pre-install if needed. Thanks!

Comment: @HristoTorbov Windows server can do that yes, because its a server OS. Microsoft does not want consumers to do this on a much cheaper OS, so to my understanding this cannot be done in say... Windows 10.